# How do I correctly set up Omniauth + Devise + multiple providers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, twitter, devise

My facebook authentication works. My twitter login however only works on localhost. My google does not work at all.
For google, I get the error:

```
400. That’s an error.
Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
The redirect URI in the request: http://unstarv.herokuapp.com/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback did not match a registered redirect URI.
```

For Twitter I get a similar problem in production on heroku though localhost works for Twitter login.

The Redirect URI I set up in both the twitter and google apps is :

```
  http://unstarv.herokuapp.com
```

While the URLs I get after trying to log in these apps are:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
http://unstarv.herokuapp.com/users/auth/twitter/callback?oauth_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Did I set up correctly my redirect & Callback URI s ? How come the Twitter login works on localhost but not on heroku ?
Thanks !!!

Comment: Have you set the callback uri for google in their console? for example `http://unstarv.herokuapp.com/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback`

Comment: Do you have any config in your devise initializer?

Answer (score 1):

You shoud add this in your google console

`http://unstarv.herokuapp.com/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback`

While on Twitter I set

`http://unstarv.herokuapp.com/` as a callback URL